# ¿Por qué max-width no afecta a dispositivos móviles?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Dentro de mi código CSS3 tengo el siguiente **fragmento al final del documento**:

```
@media (max-width:450px){
    .swiper-button-next,
    .swiper-button-prev{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Este **funciona perfectamente en ordenadores** (los botones del slider desaparecen):

[image: sto1]

Pero **no funciona en móviles** (los botones del slider aparecen en lugar de ocultarse):

[image: sto2]

¿Por qué? Cualquier archivo de la web funciona perfectamente y no hay errores más allá de advertencias y fallos por algo de Google Maps (tengo implementado un mapa en la web) los cuales no dan ningún problema visible en la web.

Yo entiendo que *max-width* toma **por referencia la ventana del navegador**. Si el móvil tiene 350px de ancho en su pantalla, el navegador tendrá un máximo de 350px, lo cual es menor que 450px. Entonces, *max-width* debería funcionar, pero el navegador no lo interpreta bien y no sé por qué.

Sin embargo, **el código funciona bien para móviles si cambio *max-width* por *max-devide-width***. Este arreglo trae dos problemas.

El primero es que *max-device-width* hace **referencia a la pantalla del dispositivo** y no a la ventana del navegador, luego debería hacer una copia de cada media query para hacer una versión "device" para cada una, lo cual es una mala práctica.

El segundo problema es que no se resuelve el problema original: *max-width* sigue sin funcionar aunque atribuya sus funciones a *max-device-width*.

Para que sea más fácil el estudio del caso, **he simplificado mi código**:

**HTML5**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta viewport="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant01</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery-js/1.4.0/css/lightgallery.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Header section starts-->
    <section class="header">
        <a href="#home" class="logo"><i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>FOOD</a>

        <nav class="navbar">
            <a href="#home">HOME</a>
            <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="#food">FOOD</a>
            <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
            <a href="#menu">MENU</a>
            <a href="#order">ORDER</a>
            <a href="#blogs">BLOGS</a>
        </nav>

        <div id="menu-btn" class="fas fa-bars">

        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Header section ends-->
    <!--Home section starts-->
    <section class="home" id="home">
        <div class="swiper home-slider">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide slide">
                    <div class="content">
                        <span>outstanding food</span>
                        <h3>delicious cooking</h3>
                        <a href="" class="btn">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide slide" style="background: url(./images/home-slide-2.jpg) no-repeat">
                    <div class="content">
                        <span>outstanding food</span>
                        <h3>morning moment</h3>
                        <a href="" class="btn">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide slide" style="background: url(./images/home-slide-3.jpg) no-repeat">
                    <div class="content">
                        <span>outstanding food</span>
                        <h3>authentic kitchen</h3>
                        <a href="" class="btn">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--Home section ends-->
</body>
```

**CSS3**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis:wght@200;300;400;500;600&family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400&display=swap');

@keyframes fadeIn{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(-4rem) scale(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

:root{
    --peru: #cd9452;
    --black: #222;
    --white: #fff;
    --light-black: #666;
    --light-white: #ccc;
    --light-bg: #f5f5f5;
    --dark-bg: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    --border: 0.1rem solid #aaa;
    --box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

*{
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.43,1.1,0.62,1.08);
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

* > img{
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

html{
    font-size: 62.5%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 6rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 1rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: var(--white);
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: var(--peru);
}

section{
    padding: 5rem 10%;
}

.header{
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    position: fixed;/*position: sticky;*/
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background-color: var(--white);
    z-index: 1000;
}

.header .logo{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: var(--black);
}

.header .logo i{
    color: var(--peru);
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
.header .navbar a{
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    color: var(--light-black);
}

.header .navbar a:hover{
    color: var(--peru);
}

#menu-btn{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--black);
    display: none;
}

.home{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: var(--black);
}

.home .slide{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url(./images/home-slide-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.home .slide::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--dark-bg);
    z-index: -1;
}

.home .slide .content{
    text-align: center;
    width: 70rem;
    display: none;
}

.home .swiper-slide-active .content{
    display: inline-block;
}

.home .slide .content span{
    font-size: 3rem;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    color: var(--light-white);
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.54,1.3,0.63,1.34) 0.3s backwards;
}

.home .slide .content h3{
    font-size: 8vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: var(--white);
    text-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.54,1.3,0.63,1.34) 0.5s backwards;
}

.home .slide .content .btn{
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.54,1.3,0.63,1.34) 0.7s backwards;
}

.btn{
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: var(--peru);
    color: var(--white);
    font-size: 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1rem 3rem;
}

.btn:hover{
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    line-height: 5rem;
    background-color: var(--white);
    color: var(--black);
}

.swiper-button-next:hover,
.swiper-button-prev:hover{
    background-color: var(--peru);
    color: var(--white);
}

.swiper-button-next::after,
.swiper-button-prev::after{
    font-size: 2rem;
}

@media (max-width:1200px){
    section{
        padding: 3rem 5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width:990px){
    section{
        padding: 3rem 2rem;
    }
    html{
        font-size: 55%;
    }
    .home .slide .content h3{
        font-size: 15vw;
    }
}

@media (max-width:750px){
    .header .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:99%; left:0; right:0;
        background-color: var(--white);
        border-top: var(--border);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 0);
    }
    #menu-btn{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .fa-times{
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .header .navbar.active{
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    }
    .header .navbar a{
        display: block;
        margin: 2rem;
    }
}

@media (max-width:450px){
    html{
        font-size: 50%;
    }
    .home .slide .content h3{
        font-size: 6rem;
    }
    .swiper-button-next,
    .swiper-button-prev{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Así pues, **¿por qué en el móvil no desaparecen los botones del slider?** Gracias.

Comment: has probado a quitarle el `(max-width:450px)` al @media que has puesto al principio? Con eso estás filtrando por tamaño del dispositivo, y seguramente en el móvil, tengas menos tamaño que ese, por lo que no entra

Comment: Por si acaso, he probado lo que dices y obviamente salta un error porque el media-query necesita de su parámetro entre paréntesis para funcionar. Si a ti te va bien así, me gustaría saber cómo lo hiciste porque lo mismo estoy omitiendo algo

Answer (score 0):

El único problema es la **meta-etiqueta del viewport**, la cual debería ser tal que:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Hecha la corrección, funciona perfectamente.